# Testers can't download AppBundle build from the App Distribution

Tags: firebase, google-play, android-app-bundle, firebase-app-distribution

I started to distribute application by Firebase App Distribution using AppBundle instead of APK. But when testers are trying to download build from "App Tester" application it opens Play Store but it opens "Internal beta" page, not Internal App sharing page with this build. Clearing data of Play Store application helps and they see correct Internal App Sharing page with correct build, but only once, when they are trying to download another build it opens "Internal beta" page and they need to clear data again.

I checked on my phones, on two test devices where I have only one authorised account in Play Store, everything works fine. But on my personal device where I have two account I see this issue. Testers have only one account on device but also have this issue, so I don't thing that the problem with amount of accounts.

Has anyone had this issue before and can help me resolve it?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you manage to solve?

Comment: I couldn't find solution. But in one day it just start working. I guess it was some problem with Google Play Store, and in some update they fixed it.